# C# copying file to new folder and renaming special character

Tags: c#, file, scripting, copy

I am in the process of trying to do a single file copy to mutiple subdirectories while also chaning a "placeholder" (the symbole &) to a diffrent chariter.

Original file in one directory
AJWCLN&.txt

Final files wanted to be placed in different directories. 
\temp1\AJWCLNC.txt (changing the "&" Symbol to the letter C in the Temp sub directory)
\temp2\AJWCLND.txt (chaining the "&" symbol to the letter D)

I need to do this for about 20 different directories and I need to make the & to a different letter for each directory.

Thank you in advance for all of your help.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `File.Copy` to copy a file around with different names.

this program demonstrates:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            File.Copy("c:\\myFile.ext", "c:\\temp\\myFile2.ext");
        }
    }
}
```

you can also use `String.Format()` for your placeholders, or if `&` absolutely must be the placeholder, `String.Replace` will do

```
File.Copy("AJWCLN&.txt", String.Format("c:\\temp\\AJWCLN{0}.txt", "C") );
```

.

```
File.Copy("AJWCLN&.txt", "c:\\temp\\AJWCLN&.txt".Replace('&', 'C') );
```

Comment: Documentation for File.Copy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
string fileName = "AJWCLN&.txt";
string newfileName="";
string destFile = "";
string sourcePath = @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder";
string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);

for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
{
    newfileName = fileName.Replace('&', Convert.ToChar( i + 65 ));
    targetPath =  @("C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\temp" + i+1);
    string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, newfileName);
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
    }
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
}
```

Some Sources:

[How to: Copy, Delete, and Move Files and Folders (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts.aspx)

[How can I rename a file in C#?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/435a2692-6161-4039-bfa9-5e6211d90c49/)